# spring contextconfiguration using bean several times

Tags: spring, integration-testing, springjunit4classrunner

Given a class that does some component testing. I want to mock the fooService.send only one times in the test and use it in aService and bService:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AComponentTestConfiguration.class)
public class AComponentTest {

    @Autowired
    private AService aService;

    @Autowired
    private BService bService;

    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    // ... when(fooService.send(any())).thenReturn(response); 
}
```

And the configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class AComponentTestConfiguration {

    private CService cService = new CService(); // 1

    @Bean public FooService fooService() { return mock(FooService.class); } // 2
    @Bean public BarService barService() { return new BarService(); } // 3

    @Bean public AService aService() { return new AService(fooService(), barService(), cService); } // 4
    @Bean public BService bService() { return new AService(fooService(), barService(), cService); }
}
```

How can I use service instances or mocks that must be provided to several beans?

1: Use a private variable in the instances of AService and BService
2, 3: Use functions - that would lead to 2 instances for FooService and BarService, right?
4: Which option must be used for mocks and real service instances?

Comment: 2 and 3 no... There will be a single instance of the mock and `BarService`.